# message appear in the same div after clicking on button

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, button

this is my form:

```
<div class="notification">
            <p style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">Enter your email to notify you when the app you selected become available.</p>
                <form class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputemail"></label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputemail" placeholder="Email Address" size="25">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="displayMessage()">NOTIFY ME</button>
                    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">*we will never sell<br>your email</small>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

when i click on NOTIFY ME button, i want my my form to disappear and i want to put a message inside that notification div, like this: [message after click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vmn8.png)
what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you post your JS code as well?

Comment: You are using a `form` with a `submit` button. This will cause the page to create a new request and response from the server. Are you or do you plan to use the submit event to send the form info via AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that when you click the button the browser will refresh the page so you need to add a listening and prevent the default. From there I simple got the div element by Id and change the innnerHTML attribute.

```
<script>

let string = 'We will email you when your app becomes available'

function handleClick(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  let notifDiv = document.getElementById("notifications");
  notifDiv.innerHTML = string
}

document.getElementById("notifications").addEventListener("click", handleClick)

</script>
```

Comment: I'd ad a quick explanation to what your code does or comment the important lines of the code to further clarify what it does for those less familiar with javascript.

Comment: @JonP Thank you sir i just did if you have any other comments please let me know because I am always trying to improve my ability to help others!

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery to change the content of the div has class "notification".

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $(".notification").html('<p><center><b>We will email you when your app becomes available.</b></center></p>');
  });
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="notification">
            <p style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">Enter your email to notify you when the app you selected become available.</p>
                <form class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputemail"></label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputemail" placeholder="Email Address" size="25">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">NOTIFY ME</button>
                    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">*we will never sell<br>your email</small>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Why introduce jQuery when it is not mentioned in the question and the results can easily be achieved without it?

Comment: Without javascript or jquery how is it possible to load contents in the same container div? :|

Comment: I'm not saying no javascript, I'm saying jQuery is not required. Also the `center` tag is well and truly [obsolete now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center).